# Show Custom Post based on selected custom taxonomy in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, filter, custom-post-type, categories, custom-taxonomy

In the current website i am building i build the following functionality.

Current situation to give a better understanding of the problem.

There is a page called blog. This page display's all the blogs (posts) in a list. There is a aside with all the categories the posts have. The user can select a category. Once the user clicks on it the user will go to the category.php and see all the posts that have that specific category.

I want to create the same scenario but than with a custom post type. I have a template part; 'offer-list-template.php'

offer-list-template.php (here i get all the offers and display them);

```
  <?php
      // set up or arguments for our custom query
      $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
      $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'Offers',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged
      );
      // create a new instance of WP_Query
      $the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
    ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); // run the loop ?>
  <?php

   //$objectData is used in post-listing-item.php

    $objectData->title = get_the_title($post);
    $objectData->content = get_the_content($post);
    $objectData->permalink = get_the_permalink($post);
    $objectData->thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post);
    $objectData->posttype = get_post_type($post);

    include(locate_template('template-parts/post-listing-item.php'));
  ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

In the same file there is the aside which shows the categories. **offer_category** is the taxonomy slug.

```
  <?php $terms = get_terms( 'offer_category' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        // The $term is an object, so we don't need to specify the $taxonomy.
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

        // If there was an error, continue to the next term.
        if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        // We successfully got a link. Print it out.
        echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a><span>('. $term->count . ')</span></li>';
    }
    ?>
    </ul
```

The result is:

[image]

If the user clicks on the categorie it goes to: taxonomy-offer-category.php (taxonomy-slug.php)

Here i need to display the posts (post_type->offers) that have the selected category.

Registration of the custom post type:

```
//Register Custom post type for Offers.
function create_posttype_offer() {
  $args = array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => __('Offers', ''),
      'singular_name' => __('Offer'),
      'all_items' => __('All Offers'),
      'add_new_item' => __('Add New Offer'),
      'edit_item' => __('Edit Offer'),
      'view_item' => __('View Offer')
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'Offers'),
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'menu_position' => 70,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-star-filled'
    );
  register_post_type('Offers', $args);
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype_offer');

// Register Custom Categoeries for Custom Post Type Offers
function taxonomies_offer() {
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Categories' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Categories' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Category' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Category' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Category' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Category' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Categories' ),
    );

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    );

register_taxonomy( 'offer_category', 'offers', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'taxonomies_offer', 0 );
```

When i use the default post type and i call category.php which has the following code is will display the posts with the selected category. But with a custom post type i can't find a way to manage it.

```
  <?php if (have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); // run the loop ?>
    <?php

     //$objectData is used in post-listing-item.php

      $objectData->title = get_the_title($post);
      $objectData->content = get_the_content($post);
      $objectData->permalink = get_the_permalink($post);
      $objectData->thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post);
      $objectData->posttype = get_post_type($post);

      include(locate_template('template-parts/post-listing-item.php'));
    ?>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is the post-listing-item (view)

```
<article class="post-item">
     <figure>
       <?php echo $objectData->thumbnail ?>
     </figure>

     <div class="content">
       <a href="<?php echo $objectData->permalink ?>">
           <h2><?php echo $objectData->title ?></h2>
       </a>

       <p><?php echo $objectData->content ?></p>

       <div class="read-more-button">
         <a href="<?php echo $objectData->permalink ?>">read more
         <span>
           <svg class="next-arrow"><use xlink:href="#next-arrow" /></svg>
         </span>
         </a>
       </div>
     </div>
 </article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

I got the taxonomy and slug from the url and used that in the query.

```
  <?php

     $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
     $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );

      $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'offers',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomyName,
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term_slug,
              )
            ),
          ));
      ?>

        <ul>
          <?php while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
          <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: I just retrieved the title, but i can get everything i need from the object.

Answer (score 0):

By understanding, you have to have a query for having all the custom taxonomy post to load by the following code:

```
$terms = get_terms( 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'offer_category',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            )
        );  

foreach ($terms as $term){
     $args = array(
           'post_type' => 'Offers',
           'tax_query' => array(
                                 array(
                                     'taxonomy' => 'offer_category',
                                     'field'    => 'slug',
                                     'terms'    =>  $term->slug,
                                  ),
                          ),
             );
      $query = new WP_Query($args);
      if($query->have_posts()): while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();   

            the_title();
            the_content();
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();
      endif;
 }
```

Hope this works for you

Comment: I just found it it, it is close to what i have, the only thing i don't understand from your code is why you get the taxonomy twice? first in the term and than it the tax_query again. Still thank you for the effort!